# Use a class in aspx code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

First of all I would like to say that I have not experience with the .NET framework. I've the following problem. From Javascript, I perform a call to an aspx page, which has the following c# code behind:

```
using System;
using Decoder;

namespace Decoder
{
public class PDF_Generator : System.Web.UI.Page
{
private string decodedPDF;
private string base64EncodedPDF;
Decoder.Decoder decoder = new Decoder();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventsArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        this.base64EncodedPDF = Request.Params["encodedString"]; //get encoded string from js
        this.decodedPDF = decoder.decodeFromBase64toString(this.base64EncodedPDF); //decode string

        byte[] pdfByteStream = decoder.getBytesFromString(this.decodedPDF);

        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        //Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"summary.pdf\"");
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", pdfByteStream.Length.toString());
        Response.BinaryWrite(pdfByteStream);
        Response.End();
    }
}
}
}
```

I would like to use my class Decoder.cs in PDF_Generator, but I receive the following error:

> CS0234: The type or namespace 'Decoder' does not exist in the class or
>   namespace 'Decoder' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

My aspx file is this:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Decoder"%>
<%@ Page language="c#" src="Scipafi_PDF.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="PDF_Generator" %>
```

Thanks in advance for all your advices.

Comment: There is *a lot* of ambiguity in your use of the symbol `Decoder`.  What is the full namespace of the `Decoder` class?  Where do you define that class?  In general, giving *as many things as possible* the *same exact name* leads to confusion for the compiler.

Comment: As a Rule of Thumb, never name your class and the namespace the same.  Think of a different name for your class, or change the namespace to not have the word "Decoder" in it.  You might even have 3 levels of ambiguity "Decoder.Decoder.Decoder"... because you have using Decoder; up there.  That or you typed it out manually even though you have the using statement.

Answer (score 2):

You are importing the Decoder Namespace twice, once in your code behind (`using Decoder;`) and once in your aspx page (`<%@ Import Namespace="Decoder"%>`). I wonder if that may be the problem. Try removing

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Decoder"%>
```

from your aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

If looks like you've re-written code for things that are already in the .Net framework. See [`System.Convert.ToBase64String()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`System.Convert.FromBase64String()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This is a solution to the problem but I'm not sure it actually answers the question asked (why can't he access the class). The fact the code already exists elsewhere isn't a reason for the class to be inaccessible.

Comment: I solved my problem with the functions proposed by @JoelCoehoorn. So, although I can't access to my class yet, I now have a working piece of code. Now I have the problem to display the PDF through Javascript in client side (I'm working on IE 8)

Comment: IE8 implies Windows XP. Windows XP is now end of life. It no longer gets any updates or patches... even for critical security issues. It's irresponsible to still be using it.

Answer (score 0):

you should remove from the page

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Decoder"%>
```

and make  Inherits="Decoder.PDF_Generator"

```
<%@ Page language="c#" src="Scipafi_PDF.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="Decoder.PDF_Generator" %>
```

you also don't need in codebehind and can remove

```
using Decoder;
```

but this actually shouldn't raise errors

UPDATE

take a look at @Ryios comment, he is right